Convexity of cubic affine and quartic affine?
I am a post graduate student who is currently study the subject of convex optimization. From my class I know that affine function is convex and also $x^r$ for $r>=1$ is convex for non-negative $x$.
However, when these things are combine together I dont know if convexity is still preserve for non negative variable. Especially for these cases below.
In the case of cubic affine function, are these functions still convex when $x,y,z$ are non negative number:
$\begin{array}{l}
{f_1} = {\left( {x + y + z} \right)^3}\\
{f_2} = {\left( {x - y - z} \right)^3}
\end{array}$
In the case of quartic affine function, are these functions still convex when $x,y,z,t$ are non negative number:
$\begin{array}{l}
{g_1} = {\left( {x + y + z + t} \right)^4}\\
{g_2} = {\left( {x - y - z - t} \right)^4}
\end{array}$
My guess is that it might depend on the sign of the affine function within the bracket but I am not sure if my guts feeling is correct or not ?
Please help me with this, thank you for your enthusiasm !
